# solr 6.3 Override method tf in DefaultSimilarity class

Tags: solr

I'm using solr 6.3 i want to extend class "DefaultSimilarity" to Override method "tf()" can anyone suggest to find the location of java class and where to put the new created class.

Answer (score 0):

The current default similarity (this isn't a class - it's just a reference kept internally in Solr) is [BM25Similarity](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/d250a1463d87380420afc90e381623c0dc470695/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/BM25Similarity.java). All the standard similarities are located under [org.apache.lucene.search.similarities](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/d250a1463d87380420afc90e381623c0dc470695/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities).

If you're looking for the old TF/IDF scorer, you want to look at the [ClassicSimilarity class](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/d250a1463d87380420afc90e381623c0dc470695/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/ClassicSimilarity.java) and extend that to override `tf`.

The new similarity can be built as a separate .jar file and then [be included in the lib definition for your Solr installation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/lib-directives-in-solrconfig.html).